# Installing tightvnc on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, tightvncserver

how do I install tightvnc on Ubuntu? Have tried to download the rpm and run `rpm -ivh packagename` but I get this error because of a missing dependency:

```
    /bin/sh is needed by tightvnc-java-1.3.9-3.noarch
```

Can't I just install through the commandline?

Comment: Ubuntu is not a rpm based distribution. Under normal circumstances, one would use .deb files to install software.

Answer (score 4):

`tightvnc-java` should be available in trusty's multiverse repositories:

```
apt-cache policy tightvnc-java
tightvnc-java:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.2.7-8
  Version table:
     1.2.7-8 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
```

To install the java client using the commandline, you would do this:

```
apt-get install tightvnc-java
```

There is also a X client:

```
apt-get install xtightvncviewer
```

And if you need the server:

```
apt-get install tightvncserver
```

Perhaps you might want to look at `ssvnc` as well - the comment within the package says it is an "Enhanced TightVNC viewer with SSL/SSH tunnel helper".

Comment: Good answer. But `tightvncserver` is in universe repository

Comment: thats right. Sorry about this faux pas. Btw `xtightvncviewer` is in universe as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is based on debian and it works with debian packages, not rpms. Moreover, you don't need to download the package file manually. You need to use this command in a terminal only.

```
sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
```

If this command complains with "no such package found", you need to enable universe repository. Check this question for how to do that [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)